# Visualização padrão do eclipse com o fundo preto

Tags: eclipse

Estou usando o ubuntu 19.04 com a interface gnome, também estou usando o tema flat remix e resolvi instalar o eclipse (versão mais recente) e quando abro ele, me deparo com o seguinte problema:

[image: Background do eclipse com o fundo preto]

Já tentei de tudo, procurei diversos foruns mas nenhum resolveu o problema. Alguém poderia me ajudar a encontrar a resolução?

Answer (score 0):

Ola,

Voce já tentou alterar o tema em Window > Preferences > Appearence ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Infelizmente sim, já mexi em tudo nessa aba. Tentei configurar os elementos de background e foreground e nada. Mexi nos css do tema gtk2 e gtk3 mas nada também. Até testei versões diferentes do eclipse..

Comment: qualquer tema fica escuro ou apenas este?

Comment: Qualquer tema :(

Comment: já tentou este plugin ? http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=plugin